# ErrorListPlot marker missaligned with error bar

Tags: graphics, plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Point Renderings Slightly Off in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/point-renderings-slightly-off-in-mathematica)

I'm using the `ErrorListPlot` function in the `ErrorBarPlots` package. I want to display markers and the error bars, however, the marker appears to be shifted slightly to the left of the error bars. I'm not sure which is actually at the correct position. I'm using Mathematica 8.0.4 on Windows 7.

Example Code:

```
ErrorListPlot[{{5, 1}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

Image illustrating the problem:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/errorlistplot.gif]

Using `ErrorBar` as such:

```
ErrorListPlot[{{{5, 1}, ErrorBar[1]}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

doesn't solve the problem.