# How do I make my discrete plot thicker?

Tags: plotting

I am making a discrete plot and a regular function plot together. But my curve is so thick that for color-blind people, it's pretty much impossible to see the black dots of my discrete plot:

```
plot1 = ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[ t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}];

plot2 = ListPlot[Table[{Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {n, 50}], 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}];

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

> [image: combined plot]

I tried adding "thickness" parameter, but it didn't work.

Comment: Look up `PlotMarkers` in the documentation. You can set the size and shape and also use a graphics primitive. See this for more: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/5

Comment: @rm-rf We are starting to _answer_ in comments. This is crazy. We should set up a policy.

Comment: @rm-rf, okay I tried doing `ListPlot[Table[{Cos[n], Sin[ n]}, {n, 50}], PlotMarkers -> {Table[{Cos[n], Sin[ n]}, {n, 50}], Large}]` but it isn't giving me dots. So I switched to `"PlotMarkers -> Automatic"` and it worked! But I seem to have no control over the size

Comment: @belisarius I just left a hint for some of the newer users to attempt answering (or for OP himself to read up on the docs and answer)... not for Mr.Wizard.

Comment: @rm-rf :)))))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `Graphics` primitives for this kind of application, which gives you direct (and usually easier) control of appearance.  As a bonus performance is usually better as well.

For simple applications such as this, if you don't also need the plots separately, you can use `Epilog` in `ParametricPlot` to insert these primitives:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point@Table[{Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {n, 50}]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See documentation for [`PointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PointSize.html) and [`AbsolutePointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsolutePointSize.html) for complete control of point size.

If you need the plots separately you can do that too, like this:

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}
     ];

p2 = Graphics[
       {PointSize[Large], Point @ Table[{Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {n, 50}]},
       PlotRange -> {-1, 1}
     ];

Show[p1, p2]
```

---

In a comment [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) reminds us that this form for `p2` also works:

```
p2 = ListPlot[Table[{Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {n, 50}], PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}];
```

My recommendation to use graphics primitives is so that more complicated styles are within reach and so that code may be shared between `Graphics` and `Epilog`.  Perhaps I am complicating things for such a simple operation and you would prefer that.

Comment: That's interesting. I just opened up the Epilog page on Mathematica. I have no idea what it says nor do I think the command explanation tells me anyway that it plots dots for me.

Comment: @jak You must understand `Graphics`, `PointSize`, and `Point` as well.  `Epilog` allows you to overlay primitives such as `Point` on top of the result of `ParametricPlot`.  See [this documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SymbolicGraphicsLanguage.html) and ask for clarifications where you have trouble.

Comment: Yeah I definitely will. Thank you

Comment: @jak, thanks for Accepting my answer (green check-mark), but please consider waiting 24 hours.  This gives other people a chance to answer before the topic appears concluded.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll uncheck it. I usually do it immediately because I could go on hiatus and forget to comeback

Comment: @jak That is thoughtful of you.  It's good either way, but you may get better answers with the 24 hour wait.

Comment: I prefer the `Epilog` route, but for the second method, having `p2 = ListPlot[Table[{Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {n, 50}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]` works just as well.

Comment: @J.M. True, but my recommendation is intended to handle the more general cases that `PlotStyle` does not, or not well.