# Poor anti-aliasing in Rotated text with ClearType on

Tags: front-end, bugs, text, windows, antialiasing

There is a problem on my system that occurs when text is rotated 90 degrees as it is in frame labels.  This only happens when [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) is turned on, and only around 90 degrees of rotation.

I am running Mathematica 7 on Windows 7.

Input:

```
Style["αβημπρτ", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial"]

Rotate[%, # °] & /@ {90, 90.1, -90, 85, 95, 45, 0}
```

Exhibit A: ClearType OFF

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ehibit B: ClearType ON

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the strongly inferior rendering of the text rotated 90° and 90.1°, but acceptable rendering of text at the other rotations including -90°.

A close inspection of the images above will reveal that sub-pixel-rendering is disabled on rotated text *except* for the cases of 90°, 90.1°, and 0°.  In the last case it works as as intended but it should apparently have been disabled (the default AA is used instead) for 90° and 90.1° as well.  I do not want to turn off ClearType as it makes text more readable throughout my system except for this bug.

I tried to be clever by nesting rotations but that does not work.  Interestingly there *is* a difference in rendering between 360° and -360° but not in the anti-aliasing.

```
text = Style["αβημπρτ", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial"];
Fold[Rotate, text, # °] & /@ {{90, 360}, {90, -360}, {45, 45}} // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

1. What systems are affected by this bug?  Is it fixed in newer versions?
2. Is there a work-around that ***can be applied to the output of* `Graphics`**?

I would rather not `Rasterize` the text.

Comment: I get the same problem with Mathematica 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: @user141603 Thanks for confirmation.  Would you consider voting for this question as the problem affects you too?

Comment: Try rasterizing it (`Rasterize[Rotate[x, # \[Degree]]] & /@ {90, 90.1, -90, 85, 95, 45, 0}`). Same problem, right? Now zoom in to 200% or 300%. The 90 and 90.1 use the sub-pixel rendering so have discolorations on the edges while all the rest use standard grayscale anti-aliasing.

Comment: @user141603 Yes, that is my observation as well.  If you Rasterize *before* rotating you get a somewhat better result, though the sub-pixel rendering is incorrect.

Comment: Problem still exists in 9.0.1. I'm on Windows 2003 here (not sure if the ClearType implementation has changed since).

Comment: I used [iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm) to reorient my display with respect to the physical monitor in all four possible directions and in every case the first two rotated text samples looked much worse than the rest (although the others don't look fantastic on a rotated monitor either TBH). This seems to rule out an issue with Windows itself for ClearType and vertical text.

Comment: I've noticed similar before with V8 on mac 10.6.8 with 45 degrees rotation without being annoyed enough to look for solutions.

Comment: I have the same problem under Windows XP with *Mathematica* at least since version 7. In version 9.0.1 it persist. This is one of the reasons why I prefer to use Adobe Acrobat for rendering rather than direct export from *Mathematica* (others include the absence of control over antialiasing of text and huge memory requirements when exporting with high resolution).

Comment: I find that adding `FontOpacity -> 0.999` to the `Style` prevents the sub-pixel rendering and makes the quality equally poor at all angles.

Comment: @Simon Actually, that gives me a result I can accept!  Using that setting I get output that looks like the "ClearType OFF" image which I find vastly superior to the "ClearType ON" one below it.  Is that the same on your system?  Please consider posting this method as an answer.

Comment: A late comment: Correct behaviour of Windows ClearType depends on the RGB subpixel arrangement in pixels of our monitors, so it's [sensible to orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType#Sensitivity_to_display_orientation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting a `FontOpacity` less than 1 appears to prevent sub-pixel rendering and therefore provides output similar (perhaps identical) to that obtained with ClearType switched off.

```
text = Style["αβημπρτ", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontOpacity -> 0.999];
Rotate[text, # °] & /@ {90, 90.1, -90, 85, 95, 45, 0}
```

[image]

One possibility to automate this, and to preserve sub-pixel rendering for unrotated text is to hijack `RotationBox`:

```
Unprotect[RotationBox];

RotationBox[boxes_, opts___?OptionQ] := Block[{$rotboxblock = True},
   RotationBox[StyleBox[boxes,
     If[(BoxRotation /. {opts}) != 0, FontOpacity -> 0.999, {}, {}]], 
    opts]
   ] /; ! TrueQ[$rotboxblock];
```

By targetting `RotationBox` rather than `Rotate`, the effect is seen even with expressions that don't explicitly involve `Rotate`:

```
text = Style["αβημπρτ", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial"];
Panel[text, text, Left, RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Big +1.  This alone will save me a lot of headache.  I shall refrain from Accepting this immediately per personal policy, in case someone has something better, but I don't anticipate that.  (Great if someone can produce correct sub-pixel rendering for all rotations but apparently even the developers couldn't be bothered to figure that out.)  The only things lacking in your answer are a way to preserve sub-pixel AA for the 0° case and a way to do this automatically.  Perhaps this tweak could be applied by overloading `Rotate`?  I only mention it because you seem to enjoy a challenge. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I've added a possible approach to automate, though you may have better ideas. The elephant in the room is the `FrameLabel` in plots, which don't get caught by this method...