# FrameLabel not printing completely

Tags: plotting, bugs, version-9

Running this code:

```
Histogram[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1/4,0.12],100],
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3/4, 0.12], 100]}, 
 Automatic, "Probability", PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x axis", 15], Style["probability", 15]}
]
```

Gives me the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the label on the right ("probability") is not printed correctly. The character "y" is missing. What's going on here?

I am using Mathematica 9.0.0.0. I ran this on two laptops, one with Windows 7 and the other with Windows 8.

**Update**: Judging by the comments, this seems to be a bug. So now the question becomes: **Is there a workaround?**

**Update**: This seems to be bug, so I'll tag as such. In the meantime, see the answers for workarounds.

Comment: What version and OS?  Does it happen without the `Style` wrappers?

Comment: @BrettChampion It doesn't happen without the `Style` wrappers. I edited to include version and OS.

Comment: You should upgrade to 9.0.1.0. It has several bug fixes and improvements over 9.0.0.0

Comment: this happens on my system as well. (Win7 64, Mathematica 8)

Comment: This happens in version 9.0.1 on Windows 7 x64 too. Adding frame (`Framed@Style["probability", 15]`) shows that the frame is placed incorrectly: a half of the "y" letter is located outside the frame.

Comment: Your code works fine on my Mac 10.6.8 with Mathematica version 9.0.1.0. The "probability" label is entirely visible.

Comment: Happened here in 9.0.1 win7 x64. I encountered similar problems in earlier version too. My workaround is adding some spaces after y: `"probability   "`.

Comment: @Silvia That works. The only (small) issue is that it missplaces the label a little bit.

Comment: @becko You can add some spaces at the beginning to "center" it.

Comment: @Silvia Right! Silly me ;)

Comment: @becko Thanks :)

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18988/534

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be related to, or a manifestation of:
[Poor anti-aliasing in Rotated text with ClearType on](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18988/121)

On my system Simon's workaround is successful.
Using `Style["probability", 15, FontOpacity -> 0.999]`:

[image]

Comment: +1 `FontOpacity -> 0.999` works here too.

Comment: @becko Good.  It also improves the quality of the type, at least to my eyes.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Wolfram. Did you submit one on your issue? What did they reply?

Comment: @becko I'm using an old version (7).  There is really no point in submitting bug reports for old versions.

Comment: really? One would think that one of the most valued contributors to our forum has the latest gear! ;)

Comment: +1 @becko I think this solution is better/elegant than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happened for me in 9.0.1 and also some earlier versions.

My crude yet working workaround is adding some spaces after ***y*** to force it been displayed entirely, meanwhile also add corresponding spaces before ***p*** to keep the word being centrally aligned.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When i ran your code on my system it was fine.
Version No: 9.0.0.0
Platform: Linux x86(32-bit)
So maybe its a windows problem.
Try Exporting the image and see if that 'y' is still missing in the exported image.

Comment: Interestingly, exporting to .pdf shows no issue. But .png and .jpg have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following reply from Technical Support @ Wolfram:

> Hello -
>
> Thank you for your email.
>
> Our developers have created a report on this issue and are
>   investigating the issue.
>
> If you need a workaround for this issue, you have a number of
>   possibilities beyond what is mentioned in the StackExchange thread. 
>   You could explicitly specify the `FontFamily` inside your `Style`
>   statements:
>
> ```
> FrameLabel -> {Style["x axis", 15],
>   Style["probability", 15, FontFamily -> "Courier"]}
> ```
>
> Or you could change the magnification of the notebook to something
>   larger, which will often fix the problem.
>
> Karl Isensee
>
> Technical Support
>
> Wolfram Research, Inc.