# Very poor subpixel antialiasing using rotated monitor

Tags: fonts, display, antialiasing

I use *Mathematica* 10 for Linux with my monitor rotated 90-degrees.

Fonts in all applications look very good (I have configured Gnome and Xft to do subpixel antialiasing in "vertical RGB" order).  But fonts in *Mathematica* look very poor.  Here's an example:

[image: blurry fonts]

Note the purple, green, and yellow around the text.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Ugly.  What happens if you set font opacity to `0.999`?  In the case of [(18988)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18988/121) that triggered a different (plain) AA method.  It might at least look a bit better.

Comment: How do I change the opacity of the fonts used by the Mathematica notebook?

Comment: One should be able to do it with Style Sheets but before we get to that just try it on a sample with: `Style["Sample Text", FontOpacity -> 0.999]` and see if it helps.