# Anti-aliasing of red text on white background

Tags: graphics, color, antialiasing

The following code uses `Graphics` to display text "Mathematica" of pure red color on white background.

Then it displays all colors used in the rasterized version of the graphics.

Due to anti-aliasing we are of course expecting to have more colors than just pure red and pure white ones.

**But why all different shades/tints of yellow, orange, pink, violet and brown???**

I would expect to have just tints of red that are present in blending between red color (of text) and white color (of background) as we can see in third image.

```
gr = Graphics[{Text[
     Style["Mathematica", RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Italic, 30], {0, 0}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1/4, 1/4}] // Rasterize
colors = Flatten[ImageData[gr, "Byte"], 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
Graphics[Table[{RGBColor @@ (colors[[x]]/255), Disk[{8 x/10, 0}]}, {x,
    1, Length[colors]}], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}, 
 Background -> Black]
Graphics[Table[{Blend[{Red, White}, x], Disk[{8 x, 0}]}, {x, 0, 1, 
   1/10}], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}, Background -> Black]
Clear[gr, colors]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Is it a correct behavior or a bug?**

Comment: That's expected behaviour for text / font-rendering and hinting, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering . It does not occur with non-text things like lines / points / shapes etc. Try using black for the font colour and you'll see all sorts of colours appearing that look like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Subpixel_e.png

Comment: Can I am convert the text to something that would Mathematica treat as if were lines, polygons, circles...?

Comment: It's not just Mathematica - here's a zoom-in of some of the text from this question, as seen in my browser: https://i.imgur.com/sIyISmt.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the comments, text rendering is special and has sub-pixel anti-aliasing which introduces the colours. This does not occur with other graphics primitives like lines, circles, polygons etc. just text.

```
ImageResize[Rasterize[Text["Hello"], RasterSize -> 16], 100, 
 Resampling -> "Nearest"]
```

[image: subpixel text]

```
ImageResize[
 Rasterize[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, Sqrt[2]}}]], 
  RasterSize -> 16], 100, Resampling -> "Nearest"]
```

[image: no subpixel line]

I don't know how to turn off the subpixel anti-aliasing but this work-around can turn the text into a mesh which will then render without the subpixel anti-aliasing colours appearing:

```
mesh = ImageMesh[
  ColorNegate@
   Rasterize[
    Graphics[
     Text[Style["Mathematica", RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Italic, 30]]], 
    RasterSize -> 1500]]

gr = Style[Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Red], mesh}], 
   Antialiasing -> True] // Rasterize
colors = Flatten[ImageData[gr], 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
Graphics[MapIndexed[{RGBColor @@ #1, Disk[{8 First[#2]/10, 0}]} &, 
  colors], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}, Background -> Black]
Graphics[Table[{Blend[{Red, White}, x], Disk[{8 x, 0}]}, {x, 0, 1, 
   1/10}], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

[image: no subpixel Mathematica text]

---

Another trick you can use is to export it as SVG then re-import it using [`ResourceFunction["SVGImport"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SVGImport). This has the effect of breaking the text down into `FilledCurve` primitives which will not render with subpixel anti-aliasing:

```
svgtricktext = 
 ResourceFunction["SVGImport"][
  ExportString[Text[Style["Hello", Red]], "SVG"]]
```

---

I've been searching around and apparently there's this trick where you can set the opacity to 0.999 and it either triggers greyscale sub-pixel rendering or turns it off instead of doing RGB subpixel rendering. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71591/very-poor-subpixel-antialiasing-using-rotated-monitor), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18988/poor-anti-aliasing-in-rotated-text-with-cleartype-on)

```
Rasterize[Style["Hello", Red, FontOpacity -> .999], RasterSize -> 32]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another standard way:

```
graphicsText[x_] := ImportString[ExportString[x, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]];
gr = Graphics@ graphicsText[
   Text[Style["Mathematica", RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Italic, 30]]]
colors = Flatten[ImageData[gr, "Byte"], 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
Graphics[Table[{RGBColor @@ (colors[[x]]/255), 
   Disk[{8 Mod[x, 40]/10, -2 Floor[x/40]}]}, {x, 1, Length[colors]}], 
 ImageSize -> 400, Background -> Black]
Graphics[Table[{Blend[{Red, White}, x], Disk[{8 x, 0}]}, {x, 0, 1, 
   1/10}], ImageSize -> 400, Background -> Black]
```

[image]