# PlotMarkers with black border

Tags: plotting

I notice that when I paste my graphs in word sometimes they are not very well readable.
A colleague of mine send me a graph made with Sigmaplot. 
The first figure is made with Mathematica, the second one with SigmaPlot.

I'm not be able to reproduce the black border in my PlotMarkers.
Could you help me?

[image: Mathematica]
[image: SigmaPlot]

Answer (score 7):

```
p = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[Red],  Disk[]}]; 
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}}, PlotMarkers -> {p, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very good idea! It works also for PlotLegends!!But it's a problem if I've got a lot of symbols! Is it possible to do the same for some strange characters, like \[FilledDownTriangle], or \[FilledUpTriangle], and so on?

Comment: @Mary for reasons already explained in Alexey's linked question & answers, character plot markers don't align well. That's the reason for using graphics instead

Answer (score 2):

There is also one simple option (without auxiliary functions) to do black `PlotMarkers` via `PlotTheme`.

```
ListPlot[
   Table[{i + j, i}, {j, {-1, 0, 1}}, {i, 0, 5}], 

   PlotStyle -> Black,
   PlotTheme -> #] & /@ {"OpenMarkers", "OpenMarkersThick"}
```

[image]

To add some color a workaround can be to use `Show` and combine "OpenMarkers" with "PlotMarkers" themes (though, not very efficient).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set of triangle `PlotMarkers` from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2218/280) of mine where `halfTr` is defined:

```
ListPlot[Flatten[Table[{{n, y}}, {y, Range[1, 3]}, {n, 20}], 1], 
 PlotMarkers -> Table[{s, 0.07}, {s, halfTr}], 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[60, "ColorList"], 
 GridLines -> {Range[20], Range[3]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 21}, {0, 4}}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]