# Black border around PlotMarker in ListPlot in recent Mathematica versions?

Tags: plotting

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47956/8822) quite old Q&A shows how to use `PlotMarker`s with a black borders into `ListPlot` and similar functions.

The answers essentially use auxiliary functions or `Graphics` primitives like `Disk`.

Have there been *improvements* on this respect within Mathematica?, I mean: are there now built-in functionalities for this?