# How to improve a color in a legend to customly-made markers?

Tags: plotting, legending, marker

I am plotting some experimental results with `ListPlot` and use customly made plot markers. To be specific, here is my data:

```
    lst1 = {{0.006`, 45.67`}, {0.029`, 51.46`}, {0.052`, 55.08`}, {0.072`,
     52.47`}, {0.114`, 57.37`}, {0.092`, 62.16`}, {0.141`, 65.5`}};
lst2 = {{0.007`, 44.01`}, {0.03`, 49.75`}, {0.053`, 54.21`}, {0.073`, 
    52.51`}, {0.093`, 56.87`}, {0.115`, 61.31`}, {0.142`, 60.77`}};
lst3 = {{0.007`, 45.33`}, {0.03`, 49.89`}, {0.053`, 52.54`}, {0.073`, 
    50.45`}, {0.093`, 54.22`}, {0.115`, 59.56`}, {0.142`, 58.39`}};
lst4 = {{0.006`, 36.`}, {0.047`, 39.03`}, {0.03`, 41.68`}, {0.068`, 
    46.34`}, {0.085`, 51.36`}, {0.103`, 57.87`}, {0.122`, 
    67.07`}, {0.141`, 63.66`}};
lst5 = {{0.004`, 35.13`}, {0.027`, 38.04`}, {0.044`, 40.25`}, {0.065`,
     44.38`}, {0.082`, 49.11`}, {0.102`, 55.04`}, {0.121`, 
    63.01`}, {0.139`, 62.53`}};
lst6 = {{0.007`, 34.84`}, {0.03`, 37.58`}, {0.047`, 39.97`}, {0.068`, 
    44.28`}, {0.086`, 49.42`}, {0.104`, 56.7`}, {0.123`, 
    64.07`}, {0.141`, 59.29`}};
```

Here are my markers:

```
vertexUpOpenTriangle = 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.2], Darker@Blue]], White, 
    Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> 8];
openSquare = 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Darker[Blue], Thickness[0.2]]], 
    Darker[Blue], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 8];
vertexUpFilledTriangle = 
  Graphics[{Darker[Blue], Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 8];
diamondOpen = 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.2], Darker[Red]]], White, 
    Polygon[Table[{Cos[Pi k/2], Sin[Pi k/2]}, {k, 4}]]}, 
   ImageSize -> 8];
vertexDownOpenTriangle = 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.2], Darker[Red]]], White, 
    Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, -Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> 8];
filledSquare = Graphics[{Darker[Red], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 8];
```

and here is my `ListPlot` function:

```
 ListPlot[{lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4, lst5, lst6}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {vertexUpOpenTriangle, openSquare, 
   vertexUpFilledTriangle, diamondOpen, vertexDownOpenTriangle, 
   filledSquare}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Height along the middle line (m)", 16], 
   Style["Temperature (\[Degree]C)", 16]}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Gray, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{"Corrected 1", "Corrected 2", "Corrected 3", 
     "Control 1", "Control 2", "Control 3", "(a) 3", "(b) 3", 
     "(c) 3"}], Right]]
```

All this works, except from a minor, but boring peculiarity. In the plot the markers are shown in a deep blue and deep red (as it is desired). However, in the legend (to the right of the plot) the filled markes show in the desired deep red and blue colors, while those that are not filled are astonishingly light blue and pink.

[image]

Any idea of how to repair that?

Comment: Did you try to make a Legend using `Legended`? This built-in `PlotLegend` uses the Plot-related styles and, therefore, can cause this wrong coloring

Comment: @Alexei Note that your triangle markers are positioned incorrectly: `Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}] // RegionCentroid` returns `{0, 1/Sqrt[3]}` instead of `{0, 0}`. See discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54536/280). Also you can try my [package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280).

Comment: @ Alexey Popkov You are right, I did not think about it. Not important in my case, since the experimental error is larger, but still. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd call it a bug in typesetting of `PointLegend`:

```
PointLegend[{Red}, {"Test"}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {{Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Red]], Red, 
       Disk[]}], Automatic}}] // Magnify[#, 5] &
```

[image]

Opacity is injected to `EdgeForm` without asking.

A workaround is to use explicit edge from opacity specification for your plot markers e.g.:

```
EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.2], Darker@Blue, Opacity@1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps.