# PointSize vs PlotTheme

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

`PointSize` and `AbsolutePointSize` seem to not be working quite right in `ListPlot` in version 11.1.  For example, the [HowTo examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ChangeTheSizeOfPointsInA2DScatterPlot.html) controlling point size fail to alter the point size if `$PlotTheme = "Monochrome"`.  Am I wrong to expect that options specified at the individual plot level should override the plot theme?  As a specific example (intentionally exaggerating the point size):

```
(* $PlotTheme = "Monochrome"; *)  (* uncomment to see problem *)
testData = Prime[Range[25]]
ListPlot[testData, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[18]}]
```

As a separate but related question, am I right that the default point size in `ListPlot` under the Monochrome theme is unaesthetically large, even for plots with few points?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem in V11.1.1 running on OS X 10.10.2. It is just another example, out of many, of a plot theme causing an explicitly given option to be ignored. As to 2nd question concerning default point size; that is a matter of opinion. IMO the default size is fine.

Comment: @m_goldberg 
1. Thanks.  From the tenor of your response, it seems you consider the failure of an explicit option to override the them to be a bug. 
 Correct?  
2.Rumor has it that sizing might differ on OSX; any truth to that?  On a Win 10 screen, the monochrome theme points are quite large (about twice the size of the nice choice for the default theme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is correctly noted in the comments, "it is just another example, out of many, of a plot theme causing an explicitly given option to be ignored." It should be counted as a bug or at least inconvenience, so please report it to the tech support: the more reports – the higher chances that this behavior eventually will be fixed.

The reason why this happens is that `"Monochrome"` theme uses its own set of primitive-based `PlotMarkers` which by definition can't be affected by `AbsolutePointSize` (because they do not contain `Point` primitives):

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 10, 2}], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

> [image: output]

Unfortunately there is no direct way to control sizes of primitive-based plot markers used by `PlotTheme`s. As a workaround you can use the following hack (checked with *Mathematica* 11.2.0, but should work correctly [starting from version 10.0.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54536/280)):

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 10, 2}], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"] /. 
 Offset[c_List] :> Offset[4 c]
```

> [image: plot]

This hack isn't well-compatible with plot legends. If you plan to use `PlotLegends`, the following hack is more appropriate:

```
markerSize = .09;
ListPlot[Table[{{i, i}}, {i, 1, 10}], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", GridLines -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotMarkers -> 
   Thread[{PlotMarkers /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", ListPlot] /. 
      Offset[c_List] :> c, markerSize}]] /. 
 Inset[g_Graphics, c_List, Automatic, s_] :> Inset[g, c, {0, 0}, s]
```

> [image: plot]

Note that the post-processing step is necessary here: without it the triangle plot markers will be positioned [incorrectly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54536/280)!

Or you can turn `PlotMarkers` off by setting `PlotMarkers -> None`:

```
ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotMarkers -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[18]]
```

> [image: output]

Another way is to switch to `Automatic` glyph-based plot markers whose size can be explicitly controlled, but I do not recommend this because [such markers are positioned imprecisely by *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/280):

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 10, 2}], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 18}]
```

> [image: output]

And finally for producing publication-quality plots with explicit control over plot markers I recommend my package [`` PolygonPlotMarkers` ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280) which is compatible with plot themes:

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

fm[name_, size_: 9] := 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker[name, Offset[size]]}, AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}];

SeedRandom[25] (*for reproducibility*)
ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 6}], PlotMarkers -> fm /@
   {"Triangle", "LeftTriangle", "Diamond", "ThreePointedStar", "UpTriangleTruncated", 
    "Square"},
 PlotTheme -> "Business"]
```

> [image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the issue of default point size.

```
$Version
```

`"11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 27, 2017)"`

```
testData = Prime[Range[25]];
ListPlot[testData, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image: plot1]

```
ListPlot[testData]
```

[image: plot2]

The points drawn when using the Monochrome plot theme are clearly larger than ones drawn without any theme option. I prefer the size used by the Monochrome theme, so I think that saying they "unaesthetically large" is a matter of opinion.