# PlotMarker differences in ListPlot between Mathematica 10.0.1 and Mathematica 10.1

Tags: plotting

I try to plot this data with `ListPlot`

```
data={{1, 1/1000}, {2, 0}, {3, 1/500}, {4, 1/1000}, {5, 0}, {6, 
   3/1000}, {7, 1/250}, {8, 3/1000}, {9, 1/500}, {10, 1/250}, {11, 
   1/500}, {12, 1/500}, {13, 1/125}, {14, 3/500}, {15, 1/250}, {16, 
   1/200}, {17, 3/500}, {18, 3/1000}, {19, 1/250}, {20, 9/1000}, {21, 
   3/1000}, {22, 1/200}, {23, 13/1000}, {24, 1/200}, {25, 3/500}, {26,
    1/250}, {27, 1/125}, {28, 1/125}, {29, 11/1000}, {30, 3/500}, {31,
    1/125}, {32, 9/1000}, {33, 1/200}, {34, 1/125}, {35, 7/1000}, {36,
    2/125}, {37, 9/500}, {38, 1/125}, {39, 17/1000}, {40, 7/500}, {41,
    3/250}, {42, 7/500}, {43, 9/1000}, {44, 11/1000}, {45, 1/50}, {46,
    3/250}, {47, 3/250}, {48, 3/200}, {49, 7/500}, {50, 2/125}, {51, 
   2/125}, {52, 11/1000}, {53, 11/500}, {54, 2/125}, {55, 1/125}, {56,
    2/125}, {57, 9/500}, {58, 3/200}, {59, 17/1000}, {60, 1/50}, {61, 
   9/500}, {62, 9/500}, {63, 1/50}, {64, 13/500}, {65, 21/1000}, {66, 
   11/500}, {67, 13/500}, {68, 9/500}, {69, 13/500}, {70, 
   23/1000}, {71, 39/1000}, {72, 29/1000}, {73, 3/100}, {74, 
   4/125}, {75, 29/1000}, {76, 13/500}, {77, 3/125}, {78, 
   23/1000}, {79, 31/1000}, {80, 1/40}, {81, 1/40}, {82, 7/200}, {83, 
   33/1000}, {84, 21/1000}, {85, 1/50}, {86, 11/500}, {87, 
   3/125}, {88, 13/500}, {89, 7/250}, {90, 33/1000}, {91, 4/125}, {92,
    27/1000}, {93, 31/1000}, {94, 3/100}, {95, 3/100}, {96, 
   1/40}, {97, 31/1000}, {98, 29/1000}, {99, 9/250}, {100, 
   3/100}, {101, 29/1000}, {102, 39/1000}, {103, 13/500}, {104, 
   7/250}, {105, 23/1000}, {106, 3/100}, {107, 3/125}, {108, 
   17/500}, {109, 11/500}, {110, 3/125}, {111, 7/200}, {112, 
   1/40}, {113, 3/100}, {114, 9/500}, {115, 3/100}, {116, 
   3/100}, {117, 23/1000}, {118, 21/1000}, {119, 1/50}, {120, 
   33/1000}, {121, 13/500}, {122, 3/125}, {123, 27/1000}, {124, 
   21/1000}, {125, 13/500}, {126, 19/500}, {127, 1/40}, {128, 
   23/1000}, {129, 19/1000}, {130, 19/1000}, {131, 11/500}, {132, 
   2/125}, {133, 17/1000}, {134, 19/1000}, {135, 17/1000}, {136, 
   27/1000}, {137, 11/500}, {138, 21/1000}, {139, 23/1000}, {140, 
   21/1000}, {141, 1/40}, {142, 7/500}, {143, 3/125}, {144, 
   19/1000}, {145, 19/1000}, {146, 3/250}, {147, 21/1000}, {148, 
   2/125}, {149, 13/1000}, {150, 9/500}, {151, 3/200}, {152, 
   9/1000}, {153, 9/1000}, {154, 1/125}, {155, 7/500}, {156, 
   9/1000}, {157, 3/250}, {158, 9/1000}, {159, 1/100}, {160, 
   3/250}, {161, 3/500}, {162, 11/1000}, {163, 13/1000}, {164, 
   1/500}, {165, 7/1000}, {166, 1/200}, {167, 1/125}, {168, 
   9/1000}, {169, 3/500}, {170, 3/500}, {171, 1/250}, {172, 
   1/250}, {173, 1/250}, {174, 7/1000}, {175, 0}, {176, 3/1000}, {177,
    0}, {178, 1/1000}, {179, 1/500}, {180, 1/1000}};
```

Using the same code

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis]
```

Mma 10.0.1 produces

[image]

and Mma 10.1 gives

[image]

As you can see, above plots are not identical. Since I favor the 10.0.1 version, I tried to make a modification in 10.1 by invoking `PlotMarkers` option and hoping I'll get more similar result.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]
```

The result is unsatisfactory.

[image]

Somehow, the plot is slightly moved to the left and the markers are not perfectly rounded.
[image]

Is this an expected behavior from the newest version if Mma? Or, did I miss something?

Comment: Yup, you missed the formatting of your data

Comment: You can look at the `FullForm` of the plots; the only difference is `PointSize[0.009166666666666668`]` in version 10.1 and `PointSize[0.01388888888888889`]` in version 10.0.1. So you can take the plot from 10.1 and just do `pl1 /. PointSize[0.009166666666666668`] -> 
  PointSize[0.01388888888888889`]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default `PointSize` in `ListPlot` seems to have changed between 10.0 and 10.1. You can match the version 10.0 appearance with

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]], Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I seem to recall that `PlotMarkers` have always had issues with lining up properly.

In fact, this is because the default `PlotMarkers` are based on fonts instead of graphics primitives, and so their placement is in general less precise and also OS dependent, as discussed in the answers to this question: [Point Renderings Slightly Off in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/8253).

Answer (score 3):

I would like to note that your idea to use the `PlotMarkers` option to fix your problem was not a bad one; you just needed a better value for the size.

```
ListPlot[data,
  PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 6.5}]
```

[image: plot]