# Antialiasing points on a line?

Tags: graphics

I'm probably being stupid here, but I can't get my points to go in a smooth line:

[image]

At this scale they should all equally cover the red line. I must be doing something wrong, anyhow I tried to use `Antialiasing` to no avail:

```
c = {{0, 0}, {1, 1.332}};
linePts = Table[{1, 1.332} i, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}];
Style[Graphics[{Blue, Point@c, Red, Style[Line[c], Antialiasing -> True], Black, PointSize[Small], 
   Style[Point[linePts], Antialiasing -> True]}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 800], 
 Antialiasing -> True]
```

Another example of this: a judder is apparent if you move `t` slowly:

```
f = BSplineFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, SplineDegree -> 1];
Manipulate[
 Style[Graphics[{PointSize[0.05], Point[f[t]]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> {300., 300.}, BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.999], 
   Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]], Antialiasing -> True], {t, 0, 1, 
  0.0001}]
```

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/1364) may be related.

Comment: Your *Mathematica* version and OS?  How did you create the raster image at the top of your post?  (Screen capture, Save Selection As..., etc.)

Comment: OSX 10.10.5, MMA 10.4.1

Answer (score 2):

As far I can tell your problems are due to rasterization that you introduced into your graphics output. You need to tell us how you made the enlarged image of the small part of your output that you show us, because if you were to let *Mathematica* plot from exact numbers and do the magnification, the graphics look great, even when no `Antialiasing -> True` options are given.

```
c = {{0, 0}, {1, 4/3}};
linePts = Table[c[[2]] i, {i, 0, 1, 1/100}];
Magnify[
  Graphics[
    {Red, Line[c],
     {Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point[c]},
     Black, PointSize[Small], Point[linePts]},
     PlotRange -> All,
     Axes -> True], 
  8]
```

Here is a small section of the displayed image.

[image]