# Plot markers appear off-centre

Tags: plotting, graphics, text, alignment

Before I start I should mention that this question has been posted in another form here, [Point Renderings Slightly Off in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/point-renderings-slightly-off-in-mathematica).

However my case is slightly different in that I do not use `Graphics` because of its limited array of symbols. I simply use `PlotMarkers->{\[FilledSquare],15}`, for example. I encounter the same problem that the markers appear slightly off from the point they are supposed to be on, this is especially obvious when looking at the plot legend:[image]

Does anyone have a fix for this? The working solution in the post I mentioned is to use `BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.999]` but this only works with `Graphics`. I also tried using `Text[Style[\[FilledSquare],15]]` within `Graphics` to see if the `BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.999]` fix would work this way - sadly no joy!

Thoughts?

Comment: Your question is an exact duplicate of the question you have linked to but you haven't read the answers carefully! You **can't** achieve exact positioning of the glyph-based plot markers like `\[FilledSquare]`: currently it is impossible. Instead you should use only primitive-based plot markers. I recommend [my package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280) specially designed for this.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks your package works nicely! One question, how do you get the markers to appear in the Plot Legend? Also if you create an answer to this post I will accept your package as the answer. Thanks again and nice work!

Comment: With version 10 and `PlotLegends -> Automatic` option the markers appear in the legend. Check the Notebook from [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10/85094#comment242421_85094) for examples of use (and add `PlotLegends -> Automatic` to show the legend).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Unfortunately, this does not work. In the notebook you pointed me to, adding `PlotLegends->Automatic` causes all the plot makers to render as their respective commands e.g. `fm{Triangle}`. And in my note book (written in version 10.1) it does nothing at all. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can't test right now, it worked for me with version 10.4.1. There are many questions regarding plot legends on this site, I'm sure this case is covered. Please use search.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!

Comment: I just have checked with version 10.0.1 and found that PlotLegends -> Automatic works nicely when included in the Notebook I have linked to. My plot markers do appear in the legend but have smaller size than in the plot. The latter issue was discussed on this site already in details. Please use search!

Comment: My guess is that you simply haven't evaluated all the Cells in the Notebook. Please be more careful!

Comment: Eugh!! Quite right, my apologies! I will see if I can recreate this in my own notebook now...thanks again!