# `ListPlot` points and axes not aligned correctly

Tags: plotting, graphics

The points and axes in `ListPlot` are sometimes noticeably offset. I have a minimal working example which is pretty dang minimal:

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}}]
```

produces

[image]

where the dot is noticeably off-center. How do I fix this?

I don't think this is the same problem as the one described in [Point Renderings Slightly Off in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/point-renderings-slightly-off-in-mathematica), because Mr.Wizard's solution `BaseStyle -> Opacity[.999]` does not help.

Mathematica v11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit), running on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I think this is an antialiasing artifact. You could try including things like `AxesStyle->Directive[Antialiasing->False]` or `BaseStyle->{Antialiasing->False}` and see if that helps.

Comment: @CarlWoll Nope, neither one helped.

Comment: Strangely, the point in `Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point[{0, 0}]}, Axes -> True]` is also off-center, but in a different direction. At least that one is consistent with `Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.02]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]`.

Comment: However, `ListPlot[{{0, 0}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 0.04}]` looks correctly centered.