# connecting points from the center in listlineplot and controlling their size

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have two questions regarding `ListLinePlot`:

1. I  plot three data on the  same frame, I use `ListLinePlot`, but the lines connecting the points connect them from the  right  instead of connecting the center of the points
2. I want to plot thick points with thin lines I use the following code but for some reason "pointsize"  doesn't work no matter what the size I write the points look the same

Note that the following is not the data I plot but I added arbitrary data so you can run the `ListLinePlot`:

```
num=Range[5];

n1={1,2,3,4,5};
n2={1.5,2.9,3.7,4.6,2.3};
n3={3.4,9.3,8,4,5}

d1=Table[{num[[i]],n1[[i]]},{i,1,Length[num]}];
d2=Table[{num[[i]],n2[[i]]},{i,1,Length[num]}];
d3=Table[{num[[i]],n3[[i]]},{i,1,Length[num]}];

ListLinePlot[{d1,d2,d3},PlotMarkers->Automatic,Frame->True,
   PlotStyle->Thickness[0.001],PlotStyle->{PointSize[0.06]}]
```

Comment: can't run your code, since it is missing `d1,d2,d3`

Comment: I add arbitary data so you can run it , thanks

Comment: Welcome maya. You can simply edit your own question with the little "edit" button beneath it. StackExchange supports a text-markup language called Markdown that lets you easily include code, italics, and many other things. I've dont this for you, but please look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) before you post another question.

Comment: @halirutan   thanks

Comment: "connecting from the center" is probably related to this q/a: [Point Renderings Slightly Off in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/125)

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that myself using the Win7 frontend. The plotmarkers are often placed poorly, the lines are correct. For larger plotmarkers you don't notice it, but look at this:

[image]

On the Raspberry Pi it renders better, so it must be a FrontEnd issue.

[image]

Use `ListPlot[{d1, d2, d3}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{PointSize[.1], Point[{0, 0}]}]}, 
 Joined -> True]` instead!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean about connecting from the right instead of the center. On the other hand, to control the size of the [`PlotMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers), you can use the setting `{Automatic, size}`, e.g.:

```
ListLinePlot[{d1,d2,d3}, PlotMarkers->{Automatic,20}, Frame->True]
```

[image]