# What to use to draw errorbarplots in Mathematica 12.0

Tags: compatibility

I have been using

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
```

for a while but after my update to the last version of Mathematica I get the warning:

ErrorBarPlots` is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may \
conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for \
updating information.

What should I use instead?

Comment: Use [`IntervalMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkers.html). Voting to close.

Comment: I disagree with the close reason that this is "easy to find in the documentation". I tried to search for "ErrorBarPlots" and it gives me nothing useful, not even the documentation of the Error Bar Plots package. If I search for "errorbarplots" (lowercase) then it gives the relevant results, but I did not figure this out for a while.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, I searched for "error bars" in the help browser and got "IntervalMarkersStyle" as a first hit and "IntervalMarkers" as a third one. See this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Hco4Qyd.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now use ListPlot with Around numbers:

```
ListPlot[{Around[1, 0.3], Around[0.5, 0.1], Around[0.8, 0.15]}]
```

[image]

And errors in both directions also work:

```
ListPlot[{{Around[1, 0.3], Around[1, 0.3]}, {Around[2, 0.3],Around[0.5, 0.1]}, {Around[3, 0.15], Around[0.8, 0.15]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: There still seems to be a small offset between center of error bars and center of data point. Is this still the 'old' issue eg discussed here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/point-renderings-slightly-off-in-mathematica ?

Comment: This is because I just took a screenshot, will be fine if you use Export["out.pdf",%]. Points are pixel-aligned if i recall correctly.