# Some PlotMarkers in ListLinePlot are fuzzy

Tags: plotting, legending

```
data = Table[
   Table[{x, 1.8 (-0.2 Sin[3 x Degree] - i 0.2 Sin[x Degree])}, {x, 0,
      360, 45}], {i, 0, 10}];
ListLinePlot[data[[#]] & /@ Range[6], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 360}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3], 
 Frame -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, 
    LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 25], {{0.5, 0.85}, {0.52, -2}}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 25}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 25}, { 
    "\[FilledDiamond]", 25}, {"\[EmptyCircle]", 
    25}, {"\[EmptySquare]", 25}, {"\[EmptyDiamond]", 25}}, 
 Axes -> {False, True}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {Full, Full}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

In the above fig i have two problems:
(1) in the legends the line does not pass the mark exactly at the center (see green arrows), it is slightly shifted and it is kind of annoying.
(2) in the plot some of the marks are not placed exactly at the data points (the data points must be at the center of the mark), see red arrows.

is it possible to improve that?

Comment: closely related Q/As: [Point Renderings Slightly Off in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/125)  and [How can we make publication-quality PlotMarkers without version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84857/125)

Comment: thanks, @kglr!  the 2nd link provides the perfect solution.